# Random Walk on one line with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk, steady-state

I am studying a random walk on 1D and I am able to derive the probability mass function for the position of the walker $n$ to be a binomial distribution of the form:
\begin{equation}
p_n(k)=\frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n+k}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-k}{2}\right)!}\left(p(1-p)\right)^{n/2}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{k/2}
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the probability that the walker will make a step to the right $(+1)$ and $1-p$ the probability that he will make a step to the left $(-1)$.
What I am not able to do thought is to prove that the stationary distribution of the random walker, will be a uniform distribution.

I have tried to use the so called *balance equation* for the stationary distribution:
\begin{equation}
\pi=\pi P 
\end{equation}
where if I am not mistaken the transition probability matrix has to be:
\begin{equation}
P=\begin{bmatrix}
    0       & p & 1-p  \\
   1-p       & 0 & p & \\
   p       & 1-p & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Could someone help me prove that eventually $\pi=1/L$, where $L$ is the number of the possible states of the walker? The number of states that I start with is $L=3$ and then I could see how this could generalize to $L \leq \infty$.

Comment: I believe that the balance equation reads $\pi = \pi P.$ And it seems that if you plug in $\pi =(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ the equation is satisfied (since $1/3(1-p + p ) = 1/3$).

Comment: @Kore-N Correct on the equation mistake. Thanks :) Now about the $1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$ yes it is true, but there must be a proof. It can't be that I guessed it. What would happen in a more complicated problem?

Comment: I am not really an expert, but the "general" method should be solving the balance equation. This is a linear equation and you can always compute the solution as long as the equation is solvable. For example you can throw it in a computer. In much more complicated situations (e.g. no countable space state) I think that there does not exist a general method.

Comment: @Kore-N Tried to do what you suggest last night, I only got back $\vec{0}$ as a unique solution. So I was in a dead end, that is why I post here.

Comment: Numerically solving such a linear system should be done by an eigenvalue routine, not a linear system solver. You can try to use a linear system solver by adding a normalization equation as well, but then you have $n+1$ equations in $n$ unknowns which can create numerical issues. In symbolic calculation there is no such issue.

Comment: @Ian Indeed. I tried solving for the left eigenvector with but I'm doing something wrong apparently... the basis that comes back is a zero vector which rejected.

Comment: If the matrix is right it should be easy to get the left eigenvectors numerically.

Comment: @Ian the thing is that I am also not sure about the matrix, I have been doing this stuff on my own and that is why I thought asking would be a good idea before moving further.

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure why a linear system solver would not work. We want to solve $(P-I)^T \pi^T = 0$. This equation is homogeneous. We can look for a solution with $\pi_1=1$ for example. Then you do not need to add the normalisation constraint. In any case the chain is and needs to be irreducible, so a solution will have all $\pi _1> 0.$ then the solution can be normalised in a second step. Maybe this approach is too naive: I admit that I lack a lot of numerical knowledge.

Comment: @Kore-N Directly solving $\pi P=\pi,\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i=1$ numerically creates a problem where $P$ has true rank $n-1$ but often has numerical rank $n$. Thus the direct numerical solver for this problem will think that $\pi P=\pi$ has unique solution $0$ and so it will think the whole system has no solution at all. Least squares can work instead, though, and is conveniently embedded in the backslash operator in Matlab.

Comment: @Kore-N exactly that was the case, that the rank of the matrix was always $n-1$ therefore I was always getting those error signs. I have now managed to do it by hand, I will also try to implement it into Matlab. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ian I think I see your point. It's always amazing to discover what my keyboard can achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition matrix is incorrect: it should be of dimension $L\times L$, and the first row should be $[0,p,0,0,...,1-p]$, the second $[1-p, 0, p, 0, ..., 0]$, the second last $[0,...,0,1-p,0,p]$, and the last $[p, 0, ..., 1-p,0]$.

Thus the balance equations are:

$$
\pi_1 = \pi_Lp + \pi_2(1-p) \\
\pi_k = \pi_{k-1}p + \pi_{k+1}(1-p) \\
\pi_L = \pi_{L-1}p + \pi_1(1-p)
$$

for $k \in \{2,...,L-1\}$

This is a linear system, and $\pi_1=\pi_2=...=\pi_{L-1}=\pi_L$ is a solution. Therefore $\pi_i = \frac1L$ for all $i \in {1,...,L}$.

We used the fact that this RW has a finite state space and all states communicate, which implies the stationary distribution is unique, i.e. only one solution to the above linear system exists.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer. I did not mention in the original question, but the matrix is written for $3$ possible states. I just would like to prove that for starters and then move on to generalize. Since it is the first time I am actually solving a problem like that could you please elaborate a bit on why and how did you get these equations?

Comment: Each row of the transition matrix represents the transition probabilities for that state, and each element of that row is the probability of transitioning to that state, e.g. the $(i,j)$th element in the matrix is the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$. So the third row, for example, is the second row with the $1-p$ and $p$ shifted to the right, while the rest of the elements are zero, and so on. The equations are just $\pi=\pi P$ written explicitly: the RHS comes from multiplying the row vector $[\pi_1,...,\pi_L]$ by the transition matrix.

Comment: So what would it look like in the case of $L=3$ possible states? Is the transition probability matrix that I have written down correct? Because if it is, I cannot get back that $1/3=\pi$. I will try again with what you've written.

Comment: To be completely clear with the transition matrix: for example, in the first row, $p$ in the second position and $1-p$ in the $L$th position mean that from state $1$, you go to state $2$ with probability $p$, and state $L$ with probability $1-p$. All other transitions are impossible to get to (in 1 step) from state $1$

Comment: @Mitscaype Yes, the transition matrix you gave is correct for $L=3$

Comment: This might help: read $\pi_k = \pi_{k-1}p + \pi_{k+1}(1-p)$ as "To get to $k$, you either need to be at $k-1$ and jump to the right with probability $p$, or be at $k+1$ and jump to the left with probability $1-p$".

Comment: Proved it for the case of $L=3$. Many thanks :D I will now try to prove it for $L \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \leq \infty$.